# Assembly Language with TRN

Tags: assembly

How can i write the following " if statement " with Assembly with TRN ?

```
   If (x== 4 && y== 0)
    z=x+y;
    else
    z=x-3;
```

For example

```
   NAM   test
ORG 0
INPUT: CON   3
FIVE:    CON   5
RESULT:      RES    1
LDA   INPUT
SUB  FIVE
JPZ    EQUAL
ENA  20
STA RESULT
JMP STOP
EQUAL: ENA 10
STA RESULT 
STOP: HLT
END
```

This is what i mean.
Assume that it will be entered by the user via the keyboard of the contents of X and Y

Comment: What is TRN?  No relevant google hits.

Comment: assembly language

Comment: Assume that it will be entered by the user via the keyboard
of the contents of X and Y

Comment: Which architecture are you programming for?

Comment: TRN architecture

Comment: @andrewmakMac Sorry, I've never heard of this one.  Do you have a link to an instruction set reference or something?

Answer (score 2):

What we do for statements and expressions in C code, is to translate the C-type code to if-goto-label of assembly, then simplify.  Much of this can be done staying in C, which means we can do one step at a time and still run the C code to verify that it works.  If there are multiple statements or expressions, one can be translated first, or the other, or both at the same time (though I usually recommend against that last one).

***All of the following are transformation patterns of logical equivalence.***

The pattern for if-then-else in C:

```
if ( <condition> )
    <then-part>
else
    <else-part>
```

and its equivalent in assembly-style if-goto-label (but still using C).

```
    if ( ! <condition> ) goto elseIf1;
    <then-part>
    goto endIf1;
elseIf1:
    <else-part>
endIf1:
```

Let's note several things:

- that the `<condition>` is negated b/c in assembly we say when to branch/jump rather than when to keep going — the sense is reversed, so we also reverse the condition (double negation yields the same logic).
- that in this pattern only one of the then-part or else-part will fire, just like in high level language if-then-else.  Following this pattern, the assembly code will run the same as the C.
- that the next statement to execute will be the one following the if-then-else when the if-statement is completed, regardless of whether the then-part or else-part fired.  This is why the if-goto-label pattern for if-then-else (as well as most other structured statements, such as `while`, etc.) ends with a label.

This if-goto-label pattern is often trivial to translate to most assembly languages.

---

However, here `<condition>` is a compound involving conjunction.  Let's write the if-goto-label expansion of the pattern for your `if` involving conjunction:

```
    if ( ! (x == 4 && y == 0) ) goto elseIf1;
    z = x + y;
    goto endIf1;
elseIf1:
    z = x - 3;
endIf1:
```

Next we'll simplify the negated expression: `! (x == 4 && y == 0)`

We can distribute negation over conjunction via [de Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Negation_of_a_conjunction): `! (x == 4) || ! (y == 0)`

Which, of course, simplifies to: `x != 4 || y != 0`

Next, we'll break the disjunction into two parts.  Since the point of this entire (if-goto-label) expression being true is to goto the else part, given the two clauses are linked by disjunction, we can split that into two individual if-goto-label statements:

```
    if ( x != 4 ) goto elseIf1;
    if ( y != 0 ) goto elseIf1;
```

If either x != 4 or y != 0 it will goto/execute the else part — in other words, the then part will execute when x == 4 and y == 0, otherwise the else part.  These transformations honor the short-circuit operation of the C (and other) languages `&&` and `||` operators.

In complete if-goto-label form:

```
    if ( x != 4 ) goto elseIf1;
    if ( y != 0 ) goto elseIf1;
    z = x + y;
    goto endIf1;
elseIf1:
    z = x - 3;
endIf1:
```

This now should be relatively simple to translate into most assembly language.

---

As an alternative we can eliminate the short-circuit behavior, if that works (i.e. results in the equivalent program), in the pseudo code as in `(x == 4) & (y == 0)` — `&` instead of `&&`.  This will translate more like a simple expression using one single if-goto-label statement.  De Morgan is still appropriate for negating the condition, but the splitting into two statements would not necessary here.

Sometimes this is preferable since it involves fewer branch instructions, even if more code is executed in some cases (e.g. y compared to  0 is always tested/computed even if x compared to 4 as is already known).

This transformation (`&&` to `&`) is not appropriate in a number of circumstances when the 2nd clause should only execute if the first is definitely true:

- the second clause has a function call, or assignment expression, or other potential side effect, and,
- the second clause depends on the first being true to prevent an array out of bounds access or null pointer dereference.

Comment: i mean something like this : See after the edit

Comment: Follow the recipe described above in your assembly language.