# How do you create an if-else statement with chars in x64 Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I'm currently learning Assembly (Intel x64) for my machine (Ubuntu if that matters). (Mind you, it isn't NASM).

For the life of me, I can't find a way to compare a register to a char. Here's my code:

```
.global _start
.intel_syntax noprefix

_start:
        // Print Question
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        lea rsi, [.the_ask]
        mov rdx, 28
        syscall
        // Load Input into memory
        mov rax, 0
        sub rsp, 8
        mov rdi, 0
        lea rsi, [rsp]
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall
        // Print Newline
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        lea rsi, [.newline]
        mov rdx, 2
        syscall
        // Comparison (hopefully)
        lea r8, [.dogletter]
        lea r9, [.catletter]
        cmp rsp, r9
        je _docatstuff
        cmp rsp, r8
        je _dodogstuff

        // Exit
        mov rax, 60
        mov rdi, 1
        syscall

_docatstuff:
        // meow at user
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        lea rsi, [.catstuff]
        mov rdx, 4
        syscall
        // newline
        mov rdx, 2
        lea rsi, [.newline]
        syscall
        // exit
        mov rax, 60
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall

_dodogstuff:
        // bark at user
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        lea rsi, [.dogstuff]
        mov rdx, 4
        syscall
        //newline
        mov rdx, 2
        lea rsi, [.newline]
        syscall
        //exit
        mov rax, 60
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall

.the_ask:
        .asciz "Please Enter: (c)at, (d)og: "

.newline:
        .asciz "\n"

.catletter:
        .asciz "c"

.dogletter:
        .asciz "d"

.catstuff:
        .asciz "meow"

.dogstuff:
        .asciz "woof"
```

I already know my implementation is wrong, I want to know how to implement this correctly please.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

What I've Tried: Comparing like: `cmp rsp, "c"`, Comparing `rsp` to the ASCII value of the letter: `cmp rsp, 67`, and I have lastly tried the attempt that you see in my current source code.

Comment: You're comparing pointers, not char values (or whole strings which takes multiple instructions in a loop).  One `cmp` instruction can have at most one memory operand, so you want `movzx r8d, byte ptr [rip + .dogletter]` / `cmp [rsp], r8b` or similar.  Or `cmp byte ptr [rsp], 'c'`  To have a compiler make an example for you, call a function like scanf or `read` that similarly reads into a local buffer on the stack.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification, and also for clearing up the tags, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Study the control structure of if-then-else in assembly.  It is virtually the same in all assembly languages, so you don't necessarily need to learn from only one assembler/assembly language.

Comment: Yeah, it's going to take a little bit of getting used to. Thank you

Comment: Review this answer, as it decomposes if-then-else: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72693547/471129

Comment: Write your algorithm in C or other language you know and then translate to assembly as literally as possible; each control structure (if-then, while, for) has a simple translation to assembly; so do expressions involving dereferencing, indexing, and comparison.  Best to fully work out your algorithm before taking it to assembly: assembly is much easier if you start with a working algorithm.